# Angular 4 Subject subscribe Sharing between 2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, service, subject

My current Setup:

**Shared-module.ts:**

```
 import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import {LayoutService} from './services/layout.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [LayoutService]
    };
  }
}
```

**layout.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class LayoutService {

  constructor() { }


  VisibleSubject$ = new Subject<boolean>();


  EnableButton (): void {
    this.VisibleSubject$.next(true);
    console.log('Visible Subject returns:', true);
  }
```

**authorization.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {LayoutService} from '../shared-module/services/layout.service';
import {VoidService} from '../shop/void.service';



@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationService {

  constructor(private layoutservice: LayoutService,
              private voidserv: VoidService) {}
  // just for test
  private credentials = {
    login: 'admin',
    password:  'admin'
  };

  private isLogged = false;

  login(login, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.credentials.login === login && this.credentials.password === password) {
        this.isLogged = true;
        this.layoutservice.EnableButton();

        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  }
```

shop.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {ProductsComponent} from './products/products.component';
import { ...}


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    CommonModule,
    LoginModule,
    ShopRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

    SharedModule

  ],
  exports: [ProductsComponent],
  providers: [ShopResolve, FootserviceService],
  declarations: [ProductsComponent... ShopComponent]
})
export class ShopModule { }
```

products.component.ts:

```
import {...}




@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.less']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  visible: boolean = false;


                         // 3 Services in Constructor
  constructor(private shopservice: ShopService,
              private routerService: Router,
              private lay: LayoutService,
             ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lay.VisibleSubject$.subscribe((value) => {
      this.visible = value;
      console.log('Visible: ', this.visible); });
    ...
  }
```

What's the problem? 
When I can't subscribe my value from Subject on products.component after this:

```
this.lay.VisibleSubject$.subscribe((value) => {
          this.visible = value;
          console.log('Visible: ', this.visible); });
        ...
      }
```

Console is empty, and value still undefined, I was trying a lot of solutions, but anything was working for me. 
Login engine works perfectly it returns me on console:

```
Subject {_isScalar: false, observers: [], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
```

But then if I want to subscribe to this Subject visible returns false every time, when im logged in and logged out, every time :(

I'm a beginner but understanding of services move me up. 
Could someone tell what im doing wrong? 
Is something wrong with my shared-module?
Please answer me

Comment: Your `LayoutService` is used in constructor (is injected), but it does not seem to belong to any Angular module (i.e. Angular does not know how to get an instance for injection). There should be some error message in console regarding this. If there are no messages, I suggest you to rebuild the project (restart `ng serve`, maybe after doing some simple change in main module file) and reload the page manually, as sometimes things just stuck.

Comment: I have no error on console, I was rebuild it a lot of times :(

Answer (score 0):

It Works now, but Only with BehaviorSubject(null) and with guard CanLoad on Lazy Loading ShopModule.
Could someone explain me the reason?

App-routing module:

```
import {Class, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {PreloadAllModules, Route, RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {CanloadGuard} from './authorization/canload.guard';
import {MainAboutComponent} from './about/main-about/main-about.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './shared-module/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import {InfoContactComponent} from './contact/info-contact.component';




const APP_ROUTES : Routes = [
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'shop'},
              //The Most important!! Delete ShopModule from app.module!!!
  {path: 'shop', canLoad: [CanloadGuard], loadChildren: 'app/shop/shop.module#ShopModule'},
  {path: 'about' , component: <any>MainAboutComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: <any>InfoContactComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}

];
```

LayoutService:

```
VisibleSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
```

Comment: I updated the stackblitz and lazyload the productsmodule. I dont use guards nor set the BehaviourSubject to null. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzneio maybe you can find out the difference

Comment: What is the difference between obj= new BehaviorSubject(''); and obj =  new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);